# Adding all jars from a Nexus repo to Leiningen dependencies list

Tags: maven, clojure, nexus, leiningen

I want to add all jars from the local Nexus repo to a Leiningen `:dependencies` list. I've added the Nexus repo to the `:repositories` list in `project.clj`. Is there any way to add all jars to `:dependencies`, instead of specifying them one by one?

Thanks!

Comment: the idea behind project.clj `:dependencies` is to specify exactly what you need, and in fact to _narrow down_ dependencies that are available in repos. what is the use case? why does your application always need _all_ dependencies from a repo?

Comment: I want to develop a Clojure library to be used in a Java project. Java project's lib folder contains lots of jars, some of these are e.g. Apache Commons jars, and some are internal code. All of these jars are fetched from our local Nexus repo. I want to re-use these jars in a Leiningen project in order to be able to use lein repl conveniently when coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### pom to project

*"Java project's lib folder contains lots of jars"*

Does this Java project fetch these jars directly from nexus repo (e.g. via `pom.xml`), because it should.

And if it does, and you just don't want to manually craft `project.clj` with all these dependencies, you can use something like [lein-nevam](https://github.com/thickey/lein-nevam) to convert it to `project.clj` to start you off.

### less dependency, more independency

Does the Clojure library really need all these Java project's dependencies though? Or just a subset of them? As I mentioned in comments, it is always best to *narrow down* the number of dependencies due to many reasons: code collision, transitive dependencies, version management, compatibility, etc.. rather thаn to "just include them all"

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Nexus you just have to configure Leiningen to use Nexus as the repository. Then  you can specify all your dependencies as usual but they will be retrieved from Nexus. This can include components from Central, clojars and any other repo you want to add to the public group.

More details are in the [Nexus book chapter about tool confi](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/config.html)g and especially the [Leiningen section](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/leiningen.html).

If you then specifiy the dependencies you need in your library (and only those) and publish to Nexus with a pom that specifies these any Java project that uses Maven or Gradle or whatever to build can consume your library and will also get the correct transitive dependencies. Same is if your code was e.g., created with Maven and written in Java.